# KALI running in VirtualBox: RALINK 5370 USB Wifi driver not working

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, usb, virtualbox

Sometimes `lsusb` shows my Ralink 5370 USB Wifi adapter and sometimes it doesn't. When it does, the Wifi tab appears and it appears to be searching for available Wifis. Then my VM starts to lag with no results so I had to eject Wifi adapter. Other USB devices are working reliably. I verified that the Wifi adapter is shared with the VM (Devices -> USB menu).

Host system: MacOS

To rule out hardware problems I tested the Wifi adapter on Windows 10 and it works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I'm confused - what is your host system and which system are you running in Virtualbox?

Comment: Does your host system start to lag or only the VM? It's usually a good idea to edit your question to add these details.

Comment: Please run `top -1` inside your VM to see if CPU load goes up when your VM starts to lag. As a first step you want to keep an eye on the idle time ("id"). Does it drop to zero on one or more CPU cores? Wait for about 5 min. What is the load average?

Comment: No only the VM : exactelly the WIFI tab ,when i switch to a different tab network or bluetooth for exemple it stops lagging after waiting of course.

Comment: this is whats happening https://ibb.co/5TLDtxS , to ansawer your question if you referreing to this "94.1 id", its alaways in 9x .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109181/discussion-between-martin-and-charfeddine-amine).

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my question here are the steps that i did to make the USB work

1. I installed Broadcom BCM43142 Drivers on Kali Linux([https://gist.github.com/torresashjian/7a89ee428d47ff747b3114b0d686de0a][1])
2. I ran `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` && `systemctl restart network-manager.service` && `systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service`
3. Then I added the following to my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

   `[device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no`
4. Reboot machine

Also you have to **airmon-ng start wlan0** or **airmon-ng start wlan0mon**